# Angular Custom Directive used Multiple times on the same View misbehaving onChanges

Tags: javascript, angular, input, onchange, directive

I have A custom directive to modify my input data ... i have a input event listener and an onChange method in the directive .. 
The Problem is when i use it with single element in a view it works perfectly .
but when i use it multiple times on the same view on different inputs the input event listener works but the onChange method only runs when the last input field with directive is changed and i cant figure out why ... My Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]',
  providers: [DecimalPipe]
})
export class TestDirective implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('DIR->', this.inputValue);
  }

  element: ElementRef;
  prevValue = 0;
  cd: ChangeDetectorRef;
  decimalPipe: DecimalPipe;
  constructor(
    Element: ElementRef,
    decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
    cd: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.element = Element;
    this.decimalPipe = decimalPipe;
    this.cd = cd;
  }



  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  inputChanged(event) {

     console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  //array: any = [];
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes, 'Changes');

    let changed = changes.inputValue;
    //this.array.push(changed);
    console.log(changed);
    if (changed) {
      console.log(changed, changed.previousValue);
    }
  }


  @Input() public number: any;
  @Input() public precision: any;
  @Input() public inputValue: any;

}
```

My Html

```
<input id="input1"
type="text" #value
testDirective [precision]="2" [inputValue]="value.value"
formControlName="input1"/>
<input  id="input2"
type="text" #value
testDirective [precision]="2" [inputValue]="value.value"
formControlName="input2"/>
```

Comment: `formControlName="input1"` here one formControl is bound to 2 inputs. is that intended?

Comment: no sorry thats my mistake in the other one is input2

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: what is `onChange` here? are you talking about `inputChanged`?

Comment: i am talking about ngOnChanges